# Agresti Categorical Data Analysis - Having trouble with differentiation of a multinomial log likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution, likelihood, multinomial-logit

[image: Agresti]

I'm trying to understand how the book arrived at the second blue box from the first blue box. I'm thinking that there is some sort of substitution going on based on the pi_c.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Note $$L(\pi)=n_1\ln\pi_1+n_2\ln\pi_2+\dotsb+n_c\ln\pi_c$$ As the book pointed out, $\pi_c$ is treated as a function of the rest of the $\pi$s, so we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_j}(n_c\ln\pi_c)=-\frac{n_c}{\pi_c}.$$ On the other hand, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_j}(n_1\ln\pi_1+n_2\ln\pi_2+\dotsb+n_{c-1}\ln\pi_{c-1})=\frac{n_j}{\pi_j}.$$ It follows from the sum rule of differentiation then $$\frac{\partial L(\pi)}{\partial\pi_j}=\frac{n_j}{\pi_j}-\frac{n_c}{\pi_c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L(\pi) = \sum_{j=1}^{c-1} n_jlog(\pi_j) + n_clog(\pi_c)$$

So

$$\frac{\partial L(\pi)}{\partial\pi_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_j}n_jlog(\pi_j) + \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi_j}n_clog(\pi_c) = \frac{n_j}{\pi_j} - \frac{n_c}{\pi_c}$$

using the partial derivative defined line above in your book.